# Create new HTML5 video element throught JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, runtime-error

I am trying to create a new HTML5 video elemnt entirely throught JS. So I try to do it the same way I create a new image, like: `obj = new Image()` I write `obj = new HTMLVideoElement()`. However this doesn't work. I get the runtime error: **Object doesn't support this action**.
What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Image` class is a special case.

The standard way to create any arbitrary HTML element is this:

```
var obj = document.createElement('video');
```

Comment: It's not "did you try", it's "that's the way" :-)